# What happened to Rip Hunter's family in the end?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

After the final episode of season one I was very confused.

We know that changes in the timeline need - erm - time to propagate and settle (to give the time police and heroes a chance to correct   manipulations). This time is in other cases a few hours to a few days.

Now the following happened in the end:

> They managed to finally kill savage once and for all in three different times (!)
>  So after a few days a timeline should have manifested, where savage was killed at the earliest point in time in 1958.
>  And from then on there is no savage and no reincarnation any more.
>  Beside what that means for the other two teams who go to different times to kill him, too (and all the episodes that play in a time after that) where our heroes now should arrive finding no Savage this raises the question why Rip Hunters family is not save now?

Or to be more concrete:

> If there is no Savage any more conquering the world in 2166, who then kills Hunters family?
>  Even then, what would the final timeline be? What happens to Hunters family in it? If they are still killed by Savage, where does he came from in this timeline? And what happens to him later? If he is still there in 2166 somehow, why the team thinks that their mission is successfully done?

So, after all the things they've done to Savage, and after all the time lines have settled, what finally happened to Rip's family?

Comment: You might want to consider editing your question. Maybe make it shorter and more to the point.

Comment: Also, it's not a very good question if it's all in one giant spoiler tag. I'm sure there's non-spoilers in there somewhere.

Comment: Better? I'm not sure if not even the title is a spoiler cause it spoils the fact that the fate of rips familiy is unclear in the end or at least not clear that they are saved.

Comment: My opinion (not an answer) is that they're still dead. The explanation for me is that the show writers established all these rules about how time travel and changes to the time line worked, and then spent the rest of the season (and season 2) making it up as they go along. Nothing is consistent with what went before and, despite a recent related question and answer saying otherwise, aren't consistent with how time travel is portrayed in the sister show The Flash.

Answer (score 1):

In the episode "[Moonshot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6231884/)", there was this piece of dialog

> **Commander Steel:**  My wife has spent the past 14 years raising our son by herself.
>   And it is Captain Hunter's fault.
>   The man has a wife and son, and still he asked me to abandon mine.
>
> **Sara(I think):** He doesn't have a family.
>   I mean, he did.
>   It's just they were killed.

Here is the [script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=dcs-legends-of-tomorrow-2016&episode=s02e14) for this episode, containing that part.  While this doesn't confirm 100%, it's safe to assume that the characters undestand the time travel of that fictional universe better then us.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's that killing Savage create a future where Hunter's wife and kids don't exist

Comment: _Why_ do you think so?